# Cant access Magento 2.4.0 backend Could not create an acl object: Invalid Document

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I'm testing Upgrade to Magento 2.4  but getting the error below. I've read that this error can relate to a missing title attribute in a custom extension. To try and isolate teh issue I have remove all the extensions from /app/code/ folder and then ran upgrade , compile process again  but the issue still remains even with all extensions removed.

Any idea how to debug?

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl object: Invalid Document 
Element 'resource': The attribute 'title' is required but missing.
Line: 13


Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl object: Invalid Document 
Element 'resource': The attribute 'title' is required but missing.
Line: 13

<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder\Proxy->getAcl() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth/Session.php:229]
#2 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session->processLogin() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth.php:165]
#3 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth->login() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#4 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#5 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#6 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Interceptor.php:26]
#7 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->login() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:205]
#8 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_performLogin() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:157]
#9 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_processNotLoggedInUser() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:125]
#10 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#11 Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#12 Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php:39]
#13 Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:186]
#14 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:118]
#15 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#16 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#17 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#19 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#20 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#21 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [sitemaps/speedcrete/htdocs/index.php:44]
```

Answer (score 5):

Merged ACL is validated in development mode using `./vendor/magento/framework/Acl/etc/acl_merged.xsd`. Attribute `title` is required there:

```
<xs:attribute name="title" type="typeTitle" use="required" />
```

Try to set breakpoint in `./vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php:169` and get merged XML with:

```
$configMerger->getDom()->saveXML();
```

Then use online validator like https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html to validate your XML against XSD (use `./vendor/magento/framework/Acl/etc/acl.xsd` with required `title` attribute).

In my case I've disabled some magento modules (`Magento_InventoryApi`, `Magento_InventoryInStorePickupApi`):

```
<resource id="Magento_InventoryApi::inventory" title="Inventory" ... />
<resource id="Magento_InventoryInStorePickupApi::inStorePickup" title="In-Store Pickup" ... />
```

but I've not disabled dependent module (`Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesApi`):

```
<resource id="Magento_InventoryApi::inventory">
    <resource id="Magento_InventoryInStorePickupApi::inStorePickup">
        <resource id="Magento_InventoryInStorePickupApi::notify_orders_are_ready_for_pickup" title="Notify Orders Are Ready For Pickup" ... />
    </resource>
</resource>
```

So, my merged ACL was like:

```
<resource id="Magento_InventoryApi::inventory">
    <resource id="Magento_InventoryInStorePickupApi::inStorePickup">
        <resource id="Magento_InventoryInStorePickupApi::notify_orders_are_ready_for_pickup"
                  title="Notify Orders Are Ready For Pickup" translate="title" sortOrder="30"/>
    </resource>
</resource>
```

without required attribute `title` for `resource` node.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. For me also the module Magento_InventoryApi was disabled. TY

Comment: This answer Is correct. II found the wrong module config by uncommenting the whole 
`if ($this->validationState->isValidationRequired()) {` 
block, so an error was thrown that directly showed the module. => No need to paste and validate the XML.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and the reason was that I had disabled MSI modules. Try to enable these modules again and possibly it will work again.

```
php bin/magento module:enable -f Magento_Inventory Magento_InventoryAdminUi Magento_InventoryAdvancedCheckout Magento_InventoryApi Magento_InventoryBundleProduct Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalog Magento_InventorySales Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalogApi Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer Magento_InventoryConfiguration Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_InventoryExportStockApi Magento_InventoryIndexer Magento_InventorySalesApi Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer Magento_InventoryImportExport Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryCache Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi Magento_InventoryProductAlert Magento_InventoryRequisitionList Magento_InventoryReservations Magento_InventoryReservationCli Magento_InventoryReservationsApi Magento_InventoryExportStock Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator Magento_InventoryShipping Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi Magento_InventorySourceSelection Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi Magento_InventoryGraphQl
```

Don't forget to flush, reindex and compile if in production mode.

This is for Magento v2.4.1

Comment: Found the same issue upgrading from 2.3.6 to 2.4.3-p2

Answer (score 1):

It works for me Alex. Thanks!

In my case, this configuration generates the xml error.

```
    'Magento_LoginAsCustomer' => 0,
    'Magento_LoginAsCustomerAdminUi' => 0,
    'Magento_LoginAsCustomerApi' => 0,
    'Magento_LoginAsCustomerAssistance' => 1,
    'Magento_LoginAsCustomerFrontendUi' => 0,
    'Magento_LoginAsCustomerLog' => 0,
    'Magento_LoginAsCustomerLogging' => 0,
    'Magento_LoginAsCustomerPageCache' => 0,
    'Magento_LoginAsCustomerQuote' => 0,
    'Magento_LoginAsCustomerSales' => 0,
    'Magento_LoginAsCustomerWebsiteRestriction' => 0,
```

Then disabling Magento_LoginAsCustomerAssistance or enabling the other ones, it works!